# How to retain posted contents for later reference

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, export

I wish to retain a copy of posting (for a question posted earlier, but now deleting) for record. How to copy and save with all Tex/MathJax symbols?

Comment: I compose longer answers in a Latex file on my home computer. If you are going to mix in MathJax, i imagine you can still save the raw text in a file.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that if your question is deleted, it will be still visible to you, if you keep the link. After reaching 10 000 reputation points you can [see deleted posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: is that the Mathstack version of "I see dead people?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy and paste [here](https://stackedit.io/) (by example, surely exist more software or online apps for this) and export it after as a md document, HTML or PDF.

Or just save the content in a .text. There is a lot of apps to convert it after to markdown+mathjax.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf/15166#15166) says claim that free version of StackEdit does not provide possibility to save as pdf. (It is still a useful site, though.)

Answer (score 12):

Here's a summary of options:

1. Click `edit` under question. This will show its source, which you can copy.
2. In rare cases when  `edit` is disabled, navigate to `https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/123456/revisions/` where 123456 is the Post Id (which you can get either from the URL in your browser, or by clicking "share". This brings up revision history of the post, with links to its [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/9d140bbe-d71e-4552-8929-467c536d4193/view-source)
3. To save a post in LaTeX format (with markup converted to LaTeX-compatible form), see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15230/
4. To save a post in PDF format, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15163/
5. To save the content of comments, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3234/

Answer (score 3):

If you need to view it only, use the browser's **Save Page As...**
I do this for pages I need to study for awhile.